# Dynamically RelativeLayout and clickable

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, clickable

I try to create listView dynamically from code with:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.one = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.one );
        holder.two= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.two);
        holder.three= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.three);
        holder.four= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.four);
        holder.five= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.five);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    final Custom custom = entries.get(position);
    if (custom != null) {
        holder.one .setText(custom.getOne());
        holder.two.setText(custom.getTwo());
        holder.three.setText(custom.getThree());
        holder.four.setText(custom.getFour());
        holder.five.setText(custom.getFive());
    }
    return v;
}
```

grid_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

        <View android:id="@+id/separator" 
           android:background="#cccccc" 
           android:layout_width="1dip"
           android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alarmTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to make item in listview, in my example that is relativelayout, as clickable.
I trying with:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">
```

and/or:

```
        v.setClickable(true);
        v.setEnabled(true); 
        v.setFocusable(true);
```

But this is not working.

Where I made mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your click listener to your `v` view returned within the getView() method

```
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
     }....
```

this should work - works for me. the methods called within should be moved elsewhere. not sure if you want to implement the View.OnClickListener in the Adapter but it's up to you i guess.

Cheers